# How to Implement Deeplink(Universal Linking) In Xamarin forms Both Android and iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Guys, I need to implement Applink (Universal Link) step by step both android and iOS, please any to help achieve this. I tried the following code in my android project

I followed this URL to write this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/connect-with-your-users-with-google-search-and-app-indexing/

Note I no need to indexing concept just want to open the app from Clicking of any URL

1. First I Installed Xamarin.Forms.AppLinks NuGet
2. Below code MainActivity

```cs
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
        {
            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
        },
        DataScheme = "http",
        DataPathPrefix = "/",
        DataHost = "test.com")]
```

3. Then write bellow code in OnCreate Method

```cs
  AndroidAppLinks.Init(this);
```

4. Then I try to call deeplink URL "test://DeeplinkingSample" from Deep Link Tester

Its saying No Activity found to handle the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 4.Then I try to call deeplink url "test://DeeplinkingSample" from Deep Link Tester
>
> Its saying No Activity found to handle intent

You are trying to call the URL `test://DeeplinkSample`, which has the following parts

- Scheme is `test`
- Host is `DeeplinkSample`
- No data path

However, you did not register your activity for that URL, but for the scheme `http`, with the host `test.com` and the data path prefix `/` (i.e. presumably all data paths that start with `/`). Hence the app should open when you are trying to open

```
http://test.com/...
```

Comment: Great Paul Kertscher, its working fine in Deeplink tester  [link](http://test.com/..) but same URL navigate using html like window.location.href= [link]("http://test.com/"); not working what i do